# Update table column with row numbers without CTE or * ,

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I need to update a column with an sequential number starting with 1 based on the PilotId in the table. I have an answer from a previous question ... however apparently I CANNOT use CTE function OR *, in my expression using php with mysqli MariaDB.

A) Anyone know why I cannot use CTE or *, ?

B) Is there a way around this / what is another way to iterate for each pilotID?

Setup: PlaneID is NULL to start. So for each row of PilotID I need to update the PlaneID to start from 1 and sequentially update so my data comes out like this. The table is called 'flight'.

Error I receive.
*,

> Error updating record: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
> manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right
> syntax to use near 'from ( select * ,
> NewPlaneId = row_number...' at line 3

Data:

```
RowID  PilotID  PlaneID
1      A          1
2      B          1
4      A          2
5      B          2
6      C          1
7      A          3
```

Code:

```
$sql'
 update a
      set PlaneId = NewPlaneId
      from (
        select *
          ,  NewPlaneId = row_number() over (
                partition by PilotId
                order by [RowId]
          )
        from flight
          ) as a
';

// NOTE: I do substitute in the actual [RowId] ... flight_id
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below solution uses row_number function:

```
update A
join (
    select RowID, row_number() over (partition by PilotID order by RowID) rn from A
) N on N.RowID = A.RowID
SET PlaneID = rn;
```

[MariaDB fiddle](https://sqlize.online/?phpses=&sqlses=a9f314991acffe6ec8275ebabafcc2f1&php_version=null&sql_version=mariadb)

Result: `select * from A order by PilotID;`

```
+=======+=========+=========+
| RowID | PilotID | PlaneID |
+=======+=========+=========+
| 1     | A       | 1       |
+-------+---------+---------+
| 3     | A       | 2       |
+-------+---------+---------+
| 6     | A       | 3       |
+-------+---------+---------+
| 2     | B       | 1       |
+-------+---------+---------+
| 4     | B       | 2       |
+-------+---------+---------+
| 5     | C       | 1       |
+-------+---------+---------+
```